# Convert a PDF to text with Python

Tags: python, pdf

How can I get the content of pdf file line by line in python? I have searched in stackoverflow but could not find any good answer. Notes: pyPdf gives assertion erro, if possible something with slate and pdfminer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the command line:`python /path/to/pdf2txt.py -o text.txt /path/to/yourpdf.pdf`

You can then just take the text file it makes and use `for line in file:`

If you want to be efficient you would have to change pdf2txt.py, and have `outfp` be a python iostring, which would avoid the making a file and then reading from it.